# Unit tests for a simple game loop using SDL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, sdl

### Background

This is my first time writing unit tests in C++. I am using Catch2 as a test framework and I have 2 projects set up in my Visual Studio solution: one for my application, and one for the tests.

I have a simple game loop that I want to test. Something like this:

**Application.h**

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

namespace Rival {

    class Application {
    public:
        void start();
    };

}  // namespace Rival

#endif  // APPLICATION_H
```

**Application.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Application.h"

#include <SDL.h>

namespace Rival {

    void Application::start() {
        Uint32 nextUpdateDue = SDL_GetTicks();
        while (!exiting) {
            Uint32 frameStartTime = SDL_GetTicks();

            if (nextUpdateDue <= frameStartTime) {
                // Update the game logic, as many times as necessary to keep it
                // in-sync with the refresh rate.
                while (nextUpdateDue <= frameStartTime) {
                    state->update();
                    nextUpdateDue += TimerUtils::timeStepMs;
                }
                state->render();

            } else {
                // Sleep until next frame is due
                Uint32 sleepTime = nextUpdateDue - frameStartTime;
                SDL_Delay(sleepTime);
            }
        }
    }

}  // namespace Rival
```

### Problem

The problem is the `#include <SDL.h>`.

I want to be able to mock methods from this header, for example `SDL_GetTicks()`.

I don't want to *actually* include SDL, if I can help it; I want to keep my unit tests lightweight and free from any window creation / rendering code.

How is this normally accomplished?

Comment: I suppose this question was already answered somewhere, because every time someone uses a library, this comes up. You can solve it in several ways, including stubbing (not linking to original library and providing your own implementations of each used function) and wrapping (creating a wrapper structure which can forward calls to real library or to mock, e.g. using inheritance).

Comment: I did spend a lot of time looking, but I really struggled to find much useful information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to apply the [Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering), which says that you can solve virtually any problem by adding a new layer of abstraction.

Here that means you wrap your SDL calls in a class that you can swap out at test time. Define an interface (abstract base class), then implement one derivative that uses SDL, and implement another (or use a mock) for tests. Only the SDL implementation will know about SDL, so the tests will not even include or link it.

BTW, for a great summary of testing in C++, see [this episode of CppCast on designing for test](https://cppcast.com/testing-oleg-rabaev).

Answer (score 0):

**In the end I solved this by stubbing the library functions I was using.** You can find my commit with the working test implementation [here](https://github.com/Danjb1/open-rival/commit/27d144f503180bbaed052423c453fb9541d96709).

This is somewhat similar to [@metal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201787/metal)'s suggestion, but instead of adding a new layer of abstraction I relied on the fact that my test project did not include the library headers, which meant that I was free to provide my own substitutions for use in the tests.

Maybe the documentation I produced in the process will help someone else:

> The test project includes all headers defined by Main-Project, but does *not* include the headers from third-party libraries. This is to help keep the tests lightweight; we do not want to create an OpenGL context every time we run our tests.
>
> This means that we have to provide stub implementations for any third-party definitions that we depend upon. Stub or mock implementations of Main-Project definitions can also be provided for files that depend heavily on third-party libraries (e.g. `Texture`). Other source files from Main-Project can be directly included in the test project, as required.
>
> To keep the project organised, several filters have been created:
>
> - **Test Framework:** Files required to get the tests to run.
> - **Source Files:** Unmodified source files under test, imported directly from Main-Project.
> - **Test Doubles:** Test-only implementations of Main-Project headers.
> - **Tests:** The tests themselves.

As an aside, the Catch2 framework has been excellent so far, and has added no extra complexity whatsoever.